# App Rejected by App Store

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

This is second consecutive time that apple has rejected my application citing the following reason.

The below is the reason cited by apple for rejecting my application.

[image]

When i'm testing In-App-Purchase i'm able to purchase all the products by using my test user account. The current status of my In-app-purchase's is READY TO SUBMIT.

Can someone suggest me what i'm missing out on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put your all In-app purchase in review as well same as you did for your application. You said your In-app purchase status is Ready To Submit. So you just need to click on that button in your In-app purchase Item. Your In- app purchase items also goes for review to Apple and It will approved along with your In-app purchase.

They have rejected because still your In-app purchase items are in Ready To Submit. You can submit it by uploading screenshot to your In-app purchase items.

Hope this help.

Comment: should the in-app-purchase product status be WAITING FOR REVIEW

Comment: Yeah exactly. It means Apple will review your In-app purchase in real time and will approve if all is well. When Approved it will be ready for sale status just like your app.

Comment: If i wish to add products after my application has been approved will it be possible to add new products to my application (Without uploading new version of app). Mine is SERVER-PRODUCT model.

Comment: Yes of course you can do unless your app doesn't need any change to display new IAP items in current app which is in app store. So you just need to add new In-app purchase Item and fire them in to review and you are ready to sale once it is approved.

Comment: one last question! is it possible to test IAP in sandbox environment whose status is Waiting for review (i'm getting these products as invalid while i'm trying to test them in sandbox environment).

Comment: I am sorry I do not have answer for this question as I never came in to this situation. But it might possible you are not able to test while it is in waiting for review. Because I heard there are problems testing IAP when Application and IAP items are ready for sale. So not sure exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't attach under the prepare for submission tab.

Here is checklist

1. Check whether you had submitted screenshot when creating a new in-app product
2. Refresh the page and check whether all in-app is in ready to submit state
3. When submitting an app, make sure you had attached it in preparation for the submission tab, just like you adding the final build.