# In App purchases gets rejected

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, ipa

I'm trying to put some in app purchases in my app, but when I tried do add them in itunes connect they got rejected, and there was no reason for the rejection whatsoever. The purchases are simple "pro access" for a limited time. Nothing new, it's been done a million times.

Here's how it looks right now in iTunes Connect, I don't know why just one is waiting for review. I've tried changing stuff on the other to but no matter what I do, it says "Developer Action Needed"..!

I really don't know what to do! And of course you can't contact Apple and ask why the IAP got rejected the first time!

[image: iTunes Connect]

Comment: Hi, have you discovered the reason or how to deal with the problem? thanks.

Comment: Please check the following answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647468/app-rejected-by-app-store I had the same issue and I have sent all my IAP for review.