# In app purchase status is in review but app is rejected iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created a video app.there are almost 7 videos.

We created an in app purchase for one video and submitted the app.

But the now gets rejected and status of inapp purchase is still showing as in review.

Apple is saying the reason for rejection is:"We are unable to complete the review of your app since one or more of your In App Purchases have not been submitted for review."

So where we are going wrong.

Is that a necessary to enable in app purchase for more than one product(video.)and how?

Can anybody help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the following answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647468/app-rejected-by-app-store I had the same issue and I have sent all my IAP for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked in iTunes connect website ? In that website in app Purchase section available double check that whether all screen-shot is submitted and whether it set to status for review.If not please check and rebuild the app then submit new ipa

Soon it will get approve.