# In App purchase is getting rejected again and again

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes, app-store-connect

i have implemented the in app purchase in my application and added few in app purchases. on itunes connect i have filled all the details for the in app purchases. Initially the status of in app purchase was "waiting for review" and i was able to test in app purchase in sandbox env. but after every 4 days, in app purchases gets new status "developer action needed" and in the language section there is a "rejected" sign of in app purchase. so to make this use able again i have been using to make little change in description, which makes the in app purchase again in review

as history of the project is: right now application version 1.0 is available on app store in which in app purchases are not implemented
and i have added new application version 2.0 which is in "rejected by developer" state

so i just want to know why itunes connect team is rejecting in app purchase again and again?
also im not getting any email regarding this rejection

any one guide me what is the solution to this problem or any one else has faced this issue before?

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem. Have you discovered why or discovered how to deal with that? Thanks.

Comment: Please check the following answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647468/app-rejected-by-app-store I had the same issue and I have sent all my IAP for review.

Comment: Hi @UMAR, I'm wondering what's the next of your story. I'm facing the same issue. Did you eventually get the app passing the review? How much time did it take, and what did you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you uploaded new version on apple store which is having in-app purchase code implemented ? if not then they will reject the in-app purchase items.

also if apple is rejecting your in-app purchased , then have you provided all the details to them. As if they find the in-app purchase improper then they can can reject it. Provide them proper details and proper screen shot for the same.

Also if apple is rejecting your in-app purchase then you may can ask apple review team about the issue. [Use the Link](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewboard/). they will let you know the exact issue.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem with an app submitted to Apple. 
There is a fallback system that needs to be in place for server side in app purchase validation. 
It is documented in Apple, but VERY well hidden in tech note : 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Here is the way to do it :

"Always verify your receipt first with the production URL; proceed to verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code.
Following this approach ensures that you do not have to switch between URLs while your application is being tested or reviewed in the sandbox or is live in the App Store."